# Using scanf() for arrays in C

Tags: c

It is a known fact that it is optional to use & in scanf() while scanning arrays, but in my program I am getting different outputs when and when I don't use &.
The program is given below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n, *a, count = 0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    a = (int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j = i;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(i!=j)
            {
                if(a[i] == a[j])
                {
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d",count);
    return 0;
}
```

The program prints 5 when I use & and prints 7 when I don't. Can someone please explain the reason behind this?
Thanks!

Comment: "it is optional to use & in scanf()". Only for `char` strings with `%s` format specifier, it is not required.

Comment: You're not passing an array to `scanf()`, you're passing a (pointer to a) single integer and need to use `&a[i]`.  You don't need the `&` when passing a character array to receive a string.

Comment: you forgot to use `stdlib.h` which is required for `malloc` and then you typecasted `malloc` which is wrong.

Comment: You don't have to use the address-of operator, you could also write `a + i`.

Comment: There is only one case where `&` is optional - when converting a function name to a pointer to a function. In all other cases it is either strictly needed or it is strictly wrong to use it.

Comment: It is a known fact using the `&` operator on an array would pass the wrong type. Every modern compiler/library warns if you enable warnings as recommended in the Wiki, In short: it is **not optional**, but plain wrong. Things are worse, as you don't use an array, but a pointer, which makes it undefined behaviour. A pointer is not an array. (Unrealted: Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends or `void *` at all.)

Comment: "a known fact that it is optional to use & in scanf() while scanning arrays" implies you would benefit with an up-to-date book or instructor.  What was your source of that idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement “It is a known fact that it is optional to use & in scanf() while scanning arrays” is false, or at least grossly misleading.

When `%d` is used in `scanf`, the corresponding argument must be a pointer to an `int`. Given `int n`, the argument may be `&n`. Given `int *a = malloc(…)` and `int i`, the argument may be `&a[i]`.

In the latter case, the argument may also be `a`, because `a` is a pointer to an `int`. It points to the first `int` in the allocated space.

If an array were declared, as in `int a[5]`, then usually the address of an element, such as `&a[i]`, ought to used as an argument to `scanf`. However, `a` can also be used as an argument. This is because an array is automatically converted to a pointer to its first argument, effectively `&a[0]`. (This automatic conversion does not happen when the array is the argument of `sizeof` or unary `&` or is a string literal used to initialize an array.)

If `a` were an array and you passed `&a` to `scanf` for `%d`, that would be an error. `&a` is not a pointer to an `int`; it is a pointer to an array of `int`. Even though they point to the same location in memory, they have different types, and the latter is the wrong type to pass to `scanf`.